# Mapping a Network Drive with Delphi WITHOUT WNetAddConnection2

Tags: windows, delphi, webdav, network-drive

Recently I built a GUI app that maps a network connection to a drive in Windows. Unfortunately it uses the WNetAddConnection2() call to accomplish this. It's unfortunate because the Windows API sucks when it comes to Mapping remote WebDAV connections. It seems to work OK in Vista, except when trying to enable SSL, and it just doesn't work in XP unless you specify a folder (You can't map it to the root URL. Eg: http://mywebdavserver.tld). Also SSL doesn't work in XP.
Basically, I find using WNetAddConnection2() extremely unreliable.

That said, is there any way to Map a network drive with WebDAV WITHOUT using WNetAddConnection2()?

Many thanks in advance,
Brad

Comment: -1 This question belongs to superuser by its essence. Even [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV#Microsoft_Windows) lists the reasons why `WNetAddConnection2` "sucks" (follow the links for comprehensive [table](http://www.greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/webdav-redirector-list.html) of versions and corresponding issues).

Comment: how about you just execute a DOS silent command net use "drivepath"

Answer (score 4):

Basically you are complaining that OS implementation of WebDAV support doesn't meet your expectations. It's no wonder, cause even in Windows 7 this client implementation has serious problems with compatibility and standard compliance. I think that maybe [this product](http://www.webdavsystem.com/mapdrive) will do the job better (we don't use it cause we have our own WebDAV client and server implementation, so I can't say anything about it's quality).

Comment: That product does indeed look interesting. I tried it out, but it constantly moans that request could not be understood by the server when I go to connect. Perhaps with a bit of tweaking I _might_ be able to get it to work

Comment: @user198470 or maybe it's the server which is not exactly standard-compliant? I can't say for sure, guess you need to contact the vendors.

Answer (score 2):

I think that it's possible using WMI. 
The class [WIN32_Share](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394435%28VS.85%29.aspx) have a method **Create** with this comment: "Class method that initiates sharing for a server resource.".

Search for WMI and execute a method. You will find some questions about this (and responses).

The [{RRUZ}](https://stackoverflow.com/users/91299/rruz) [blog](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/) have a lot of information about this.

Regards.